# how can i implement a notification system in real -time collaborative application

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have a collaborative application, this application assist  several learners in a common task to collectively solve a given problem.

I want to implement a notification  system. This system should notify other learners when one of them  choose the  language of communication, disconnect, whatever the action done,  the other learners  see a notification about what  someone do

I developed   my application with  java / Java EE using  jsf2  and primefaces.

Comment: Every learner is diffrent application? Or just part of the same application?. If you can explain what is learner.. Beacuse it is not perfectly understood

Comment: hi , my problem is how to build a notification, system using jsf +ajax, i have a group work together, whenone of theme write the system notify the other " X is now writing" or when choose the language of communication the system notify" X choose english as language of communication". i want to notify the members of groups about all the actions do it . it a notification like facebbok

Comment: I have edited my post.. Please take a look. This is exactly what you need @user3360297

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I really can help you here. There is a thing called primefaces. This is a jsf component that extend and also contains a push notification framework which is very easy to use. I implemented something like that. There are examples and integration is easy.

Check this out:
[This is the showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/). Take a look; it might help you with other things also.

[This is the link for primefaces chat with push notifications](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml).

You can take a look and tell me what you think.
Primefaces uses Atmosphere, but you just need to put a tag in xhtml and handle in Js. 
The server side is very easy.

Hope that helps. Take a look on the chat; it is basically the same issue that you need.

EDIT:

I found this one which may be more appropriate for you.  Notification for all subscribers.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml

Comment: thanks Aviad  for your reply ,   it is exactly what i need , but i have a problem , if you can help me please.

in the primefaces demo the notification  appears  in my window and in the  window for the others subscribers . but for example when i when do an action ,the system  show the notification to the others not form me also . In instance when i choose a language   to work together with the others , the  system send a notification with the language that i choose.